# PiHole and OpenVPN: want to connect network devices with VPN IP address

Tags: pi-4

My situation is as follows: I have a Raspberry Pi 4B running Ubuntu 22.04LTS with Pihole and OpenVPN server. When I connect any device with the Pi VPN (in the same local network), the device gets a 10.8.0.2 (tun0) IP address beside the regular 192.168.x.y address.
And Pihole blocking does work then because I force DNS by this openvpn setting:

```
route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"
```

But the Pihole still has the (fixed) 192.168.x.y address.
What I want is, when connected to the Pi VPN server, the 192.168.x.y IP of the connected device is no longer discoverable by other devices in 192.168.x.y subnet, but only by 10.8.0.x IP address (i.e. when connected to the VPN).
Now it even appears that when two devices are connected to the VPN they both have 10.8.0.2 which appears weird to me, while the PI itself in 10.8.0.1. I expected an extra IP like 10.8.0.3, 0.4,...
Does anybody know how I can configure Pihole DNS or DHCP ? The latter is disabled because it is in the 192.168 network already DHCP'ed by the router.